# Perl: How to insert a line if match found?

Tags: perl

**File Contents:**

```
456 name1 name2 345 678
423 name3 name4 345 678
435 name5 name6 345 678
866 name7 name8 345 678
```

**File Contents After Inserting line** :

```
456 name1 name2 345 678
423 name3 name4 345 678
Name3_Found
435 name5 name6 345 678
866 name7 name8 345 678
```

**File Contents I am Getting:**

```
456 name1 name2 345 678
423 name3 name4 345 678
Name3_Found
me6 345 678
866 name7 name8 345 678
```

**CODE**:

```
open (temp2, "+<$file") or die "Could not open file";
my $point;
   
while(my $lin =<temp2>) {
    $point = tell(temp2);
    if ( $lin =~ /name5/ ){
        seek(temp2,$point-2,0);
        chk: 
        while (my $lin =<temp2>){
            my @rw = split" ",$lin;
            if ($rw[1] eq "name3"  ) {
                say temp2 "Name3_Found";
            } elsif( $lin =~ /name5/){
                last chk;
            }
        }
    }
}
close temp2;
```

Anyone know why it is deleting other line data? and How to fix it?

Comment: Well you are overwriting the existing bytes (`435 name5 na`) with the addition (`Name3_Found\n`).  A file is a sequence of bytes and one cannot "add" in between them or some such.  You need to copy it over, and add that new line where it belongs in the process.

Comment: @zdim, I didn't  the copying thing.

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing a couple of things here. When you write to a mixed-mode filehandle, (`+<`), you are not inserting data. You are overwriting what is already there.

If you have fixed-length records and want to get to a specific record, use `seek`. To replace a record, you have to write out exactly the same number of octets. If you write too few octets, you leave behind octets from the previous record, and if you write out too many, you overwrite the next record.

If you want to do line-oriented stuff, don't do mixed mode `open`. Open the file to read it, and output to a new file. [perlfaq5 covers this in "How do I change, delete, or insert a line in a file, or append to the beginning of a file?"](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq5#How-do-I-change,-delete,-or-insert-a-line-in-a-file,-or-append-to-the-beginning-of-a-file?).

I think [Learning Perl, 4th Edition](https://www.learning-perl.com) still had a chapter on this stuff.

Answer (score 0):

**Only because you asked**, "... and How to fix it?"

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use Data::Dumper;
use Hash::Util qw(lock_keys);
use strict;
use warnings;

my $file=q{TheData.txt};

# using three argument open and dying with error
open (my $temp, "+<",$file)
    or die "Could not open '$file'! $!";
my %ptr_h=(READER=>tell $temp,WRITER=>tell $temp);
# The only keys we're going to use are READER and WRITER --- anything will error out
lock_keys(%ptr_h);

# Our buffer
my @buffer_a;
while(my $line=<$temp>) {
    # The next read will start here
    $ptr_h{READER}=tell($temp);

    # Make any changes to the line - pushing them onto the buffer
    if ($line =~ m{name3}) { # only if name3
        # pushing them onto the buffer
        push @buffer_a,$line.qq{Name3_Found\n};
        }
    else { # otherwise just save it!
        push @buffer_a,$line;
        }
    # end of changes

    # Do we have anything to write and the room to write it
    while (@buffer_a && length($buffer_a[0]) <= $ptr_h{READER}-$ptr_h{WRITER}) {
        # We do have room to write the first record of the buffer
        seek $temp,$ptr_h{WRITER},0;
        # Enough room to write $Buffer_a[0] so write it ...
        print $temp shift(@buffer_a);
        $ptr_h{WRITER}=tell($temp);
        };
    }
# Go back to where we were reading
continue {
    seek $temp,$ptr_h{READER},0;
    };
# We've read and processed all of the file
# ... now write out what remains of the buffer
seek $temp,$ptr_h{WRITER},0;
while (@buffer_a) {
    print $temp shift(@buffer_a);
    };
# ... and truncate the file
truncate $temp,tell($temp);
# ... and close
close($temp)
    or die "Can't close '$file'! $!";
```

ACHTUNG: If something should happen during your update you may be "up the creek without a paddle".